# Odp.Net - Depending on the client and server

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, odp.net

I have question from theory.
My application uses Odp.Net. I add as reference file Oracle.DataAccess.dll version 2.112.3.0.
I am using Odp.Net to query database and to **registry query notifications**.
On each computer i install ODAC 11.2 Release 5 (11.2.0.3.20) from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html.

I would like to know what dependencies are between my Odp.Net version, Oracle Client version (which can be installed on client machine) and Oracle Server Version.

The problem is that after I register query notification I can see row in USER_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION_REGS table. But after few seconds this notification is unregistered and dissapear. I read that this is connected with version problem, but i cant understand what i have to do.

My goal is to use same Odp.Net files (Oracle.DataAccess.dll + some extra dependencies like oci.dll etc) in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved
Oracle server version 11.2.0.1.0 and 11.2.0.2.0 has a bug. If client in other version register event it will eb automatically unregistered after first database change. To resolve it i had to wirte persistant command:
alter system set event=’10867 trace name context forever, level 1, COMMENT =’komentarz’ SCOPE=SPFILE;

Comment: The above solution is a workaround and should not be relied upon long term. The correct fix is to patch the database AND the odp.net client. This is a very old bug and the latest patchsets for both will fix it.

Answer (score 3):

ODP version decrypted

a.b.c.d (e.g. 2.112.3.0):

- a (2) .Net version (2.0+ in your case)
- b (112) Oracle Client version (11.2+ in your case)
- c, d (3, 0) ODP version (3d version of ODP for .Net 2.0 for Oracle Client 11.2)

Another example: "4.100.1.0" - ODP for .Net 4.0+ and Oracle Client 10.0+ 1st version

Comment: So why on server 10.2.0.4.0 and client 10.2.0.3.0 change notification works good, but on server 11.2.0.1.0 and client 10.2.0.3.0 it doesnt work (like I wrote notification dissapear from db after few seconds). In both case i use same odp 2.112.3.0

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in 11.2.0.1 database regarding change notification.

The following SQL causes Oracle to avoid the buggy code path with the older version, but you are advised to upgrade the database:

alter system set events '10867 trace name context forever, level 1';

This is not meant to be a permanent solution. You should upgrade both ODP.NET and patch the database to the latest 11.2 patchset.

Christian Shay

Oracle

Comment: I knew about your solution but 1) I have case when server is in 11.2.0.2 version and I still dont get notifications 2) after alter system... all works but only to time when I restart server - Can I work around it and add permanent system change?

Comment: If this alter system fixes the problem, then you are hitting the bug. Aside from the database being upgraded, ODP.NET must also be upgraded to fix the bug. There ought to be a mention of this in the release notes, I think.