# ODP.NET notifications are not received in the client side

Tags: oracle, notifications, odp.net

I have the following deployment:

A) Server Machine:

- Windows 7 - 64 bits - SP1 (English)
- Oracle Database 11g Express Edition
- ODAC 11.2.0.1.2 (Only the Oracle Instant Client 11.2.0.1.0 is installed)

B) Client Machine:

- Windows 7 - 32 bits - SP1 (Spanish)
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0
- ODAC 11.2.0.1.2 (Full installation)

In the Client Machine I have a very simple application that performs the following steps:

1. Creates an OracleConnection
2. Creates an OracleCommand (SELECT FIELD FROM TABLE)
3. Creates an OracleDependency based on the previous command

Once these steps are performed I am able to see in the DBA_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION_REGS table that a new record has been inserted. The information in this record perfectly matches with my client settings (user connected, IP address, IP port).

Then, I modify the DB being sure that the result of the query to be notified changes after this modification. My application should be notified but it is not.

I have checked (using Wireshark) that, after the modification, some traffic is sent form the server to the client through the port specified in the DBA_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION_REGS but the client application it is not notified.

So, it seems that the notification is created correctly, the notification from the server to the client computer is also sent, but the notification does not reach the application.

What else do I need in the client side in order to receive the notification?

Thanks in advance....

Here the code I am using:

```
private void buttonConnectOracle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String constr = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=192.164.10.202)(PORT=30005))" + 
                    "(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=MASI)));User Id=dbuser;Password=dbuserpasswd;";

    try
    {
        OracleCon = new OracleConnection(constr);
        OracleCon.Open();
        buttonConectarOracle.Enabled = false;
        RegisterOracleCommandDependency();
    }
    catch (Exception E)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format("ERROR connecting with Oracle BD: {0}{0}Connection string: {1}{0}{0}Error:{0}{2}", "\n\r", constr, E.Message));
    }
}

private void RegisterOracleCommandDependency()
{
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM SCEHMA.REF";
    OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand(sql, OracleCon);

    OracleDep = new OracleDependency(command);
    command.Notification.IsNotifiedOnce = false;

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    OracleDep.OnChange += new Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OnChangeEventHandler(OnMyNotificationOracle);
}

public void OnMyNotificationOracle(object src, OracleNotificationEventArgs args) 
{
    String logStr = "Notification received at " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
    //TODO: Add logStr to log
}
```

Comment: Is you client application a Web, console, or windows app?

Comment: It is a windows app.

Comment: Have you check the documentation? I think it contains what you're looking for in "Loading and Running the Change Notification Demo Application" [3,4]. Let me know if you get it to work.

Comment: There's issues in 11.2 databases and clients that can cause notifications to not be received. See my answer here to make sure you are not hitting that bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25629461/oraclecommand-with-oracledependency-waiting-forever

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Hi all for your comments. @b_levitt, I have included the source code of the client application in the original question.

Comment: @yopez83, thanks for the tips. I had built my example using the references you mention. I think I have done everything correctly. What is more, I was able to make it work executing the client application in the server computer.

Comment: Will you try making OracleDep, OracleCon and command  class/global level variables?  My thought for your code AND the example that it is based on, is that these items are going out of scope and eventually garbage collected.  I suppose that OracleCon might be lingering somewhere since it was never disposed, but that is not something I would rely on.

Comment: Wrap everything within the try block in a using block, that will take care of the disposal. `using(var oracleCon = new OracleConnection(constr)){oracleCon.Open();         buttonConectarOracle.Enabled = false;         RegisterOracleCommandDependency();}`

Comment: Thanks b_levitt and yopez83, I followed your suggestions but they did not work. I have updated the original question with more detail about the deployment.

Comment: I have edited the below answer and provided you with a new link to more information. Let me know who it goes.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, thanks to @b_levitt, @yopez83 and @Christian Shay for their contributions.

The issue has been solved: there is an incompatibility problem between some Oracle Server versions and the corresponding Oracle Client versions.

As a summary, notifications do not work when Server is 11.2.0.2.0 and Client is 11.2.0.1.2.

This query gives information about the Oracle server version:

```
select * from v$version;
```

In my case, the output was the following:

```
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
CORE 11.2.0.2.0 Production
TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
```

Hope this help....

Comment: It's a bug that be fixed by patching both database and client. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25629461/oraclecommand-with-oracledependency-waiting-forever The terminal release of the database is 11.2.0.4 and you should be using that.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the incompatible versions listing above;
I am having the same issues with Oracle 11g Release 11.2.0.3.0 (64bit), and using ODP.NET (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess) version 12.1.24160719.

Get an entry in the USER_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION_REGS table (Host IP does not match my client IP however, hmmm...) This entry is removed after about 30 secs. OnChangeEventHandler never triggered in the .Net client upon inserts (using object-based notification).

Did both:

```
GRANT CHANGE NOTIFICATION TO [USER]
GRANT EXECUTE ON DBMS_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION TO [USER]
```

Tried the other ODP.NET client versions available from nuget now, down to 10.1.21. None worked. Wireshark detects no traffic whatsoever on port 1005 (used by OracleDependency) when executing inserts. Sigh.

**Update:** It turns out that callback failed due to IP redirects that had been setup at the server, so no blame to Oracle in this case... A tip is always to verify the IP adress specified in USER_CHANGE_NOTIFICATION_REGS.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/changenotification/ChangeNotification.htm). I think it will help you with the notification.

Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21570769/odp-net-depending-on-the-client-and-server?rq=1), if the previous link didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help

```
using (OracleConnection OraConn = new OracleConnection(conString))
{
    using (OracleCommand OraComm = OraConn.CreateCommand())
    {
        try
        {
            OracleDependency OraDep = new OracleDependency(OraComm);
            OraComm.AddRowid = true;
            OraComm.CommandText = crawlORACLEServer;
            OraComm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
            OraComm.Notification.IsNotifiedOnce = false;
            OraDep.OnChange += OraDep_OnChange;

            if (OraConn.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed) OraConn.Open();

            dynamic f = await OraComm.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();

            bRet = true;
        }
        catch (OracleNullValueException eN)
        {
            message = eN.Message;
        }
        catch (OracleTruncateException OT)
        {
            message = OT.Message;
        }
        catch (OracleTypeException eT)
        {
            message = eT.Message;
        }
        catch (OracleException ex)
        {
            message = ex.Message;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            message = e.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            OraComm.Dispose();
            OraConn.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```